# EF Core - I can create initial migration with LocalDate type but cannot add a new migration with a new field of the same type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, nodatime

I am using EF Core v5.0.5 with a code-first approach. Within my domain classes I do have some which contains fields of `LocalDate` type (https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/api/NodaTime.LocalDate.html), like:

```
public class TimeSlot
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public LocalDate StartDate { get; set; }

    public TimeSlot(LocalDate startDate)
    {
        StartDate = startDate;
    }
}
```

I am completely fine to generate the initial migration with the very basic command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitalMigration
```

And then the migration can be applied so the database is correctly and successfully created.

However, once I do try to add a new field of the same type (for example `LocalDate EndDate`), I am getting the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot scaffold C# literals of type 'NodaTime.LocalDate'. The provider should implement CoreTypeMapping.GenerateCodeLiteral to support using it at design time.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.CSharpHelper.UnknownLiteral(Object value)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator.Generate(AddColumnOperation operation, IndentedStringBuilder builder)
> at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid3[T0,T1,T2](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator.Generate(String builderName, IReadOnlyList`1 operations, IndentedStringBuilder builder) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationsGenerator.GenerateMigration(String migrationNamespace, String migrationName, IReadOnlyList`1 upOperations, IReadOnlyList`1 downOperations) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>
> Cannot scaffold C# literals of type 'NodaTime.LocalDate'. The provider should implement CoreTypeMapping.GenerateCodeLiteral to support using it at design time.

This message leaves me completely clueless since a moment ago EF Core was completely fine to generate a proper migration. I would appreciate any cue why it is working the way we can see.

Comment: Maybe this article will help https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2019/03/26/using-noda-time-with-ef-core.aspx

Comment: There is a issue about this: https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1906
Can you reproduce it?